# Changing backgroundview of a uitableviewcell to nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a grouped table view and I don't want a see the background for a specific cell, because I put a picture in this cell. So in the cellForRowAtIndex, I put cell.backgroundView= nil;.
But it don't works, but If reload the data of the tableview now the background of my cell disappear. How I can disappear the background on the first load of my tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to simply hide background: `cell.backgroundView.hidden = YES`